# fetch data from table without primary key

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I have MySQL database table which has following field and data:

[image]

Here id is primary key and its is auto generated. My query is to fetch the member through projectId. My query in Hibernate is:

```
Query query=session.createQuery("from ProjectMemberDTO P where P.projectId=:pid");
query.setParameter("pid", pid);
```

Suppose pid is 49 then I am getting first result of the table as many time as there are number of pid, i.e I am getting

```
harindermo
harindermo
harindermo
```

but when I am running this query in my MYSQL WorkBench it gives correct result.

```
  @Entity
    @Table(name="projectmember")
    public class ProjectMemberDTO {

        @Id

        @Column(name="projectId")
        int projectId;
        @Column(name="id")
        int id;
        public int getId() {
            return id;
        }
        public void setId(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
        @Column(name="member")
        String member;
        @Column(name="status")
        String status;

        public int getProjectId() {
            return projectId;
        }
        public void setProjectId(int projectId) {
            this.projectId = projectId;
        }
        public String getMember() {
            return member;
        }
        public void setMember(String member) {
            this.member = member;
        }
        public String getStatus() {
            return status;
        }
        public void setStatus(String status) {
            this.status = status;
        }
    }
```

This is my ProjectMemberDTO

Comment: Is this HQLor native SQL. Since this query seems a bit unlikely for a hibernate query.

Comment: its HQL query actual syntax is

Comment: Query query=session.createQuery("from ProjectMemberDTO P where P.projectId=:pid");
   query.setParameter("pid", pid);

Comment: Well, than most likely your model is not good. In a normal scenario, there would be a reference to Project in ProjectMember and you would query it via from ProjectMemberDTO p where p.project.id = :pid. Please post your model, maybe something related to eager fetching.

Comment: The @id annotation should be on the id and not on projectid.

Comment: This is quite a good question, but please refrain from asking for urgency. Your readers are **volunteers** and they may get around to looking at your question, and if they do so it will be at their leisure. Remember that hundreds of questions came in today, and no question is more important than another.

Comment: Yes its work after putting @Id on the primary key.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can very well write a native SQL Query as shown below:

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM ProjectMemberDTO WHERE projectId = :projectId";
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
query.setParameter("projectId", projectId);
List results = query.list();
```

Comment: @Harinder shankarsh's solution is correct also you should enable show_sql on hibernet.cfg.xml and check which query is being generated from HQL. This will help you to identify what is wrong in your query and hibernate pojo structure.

Comment: in your answer ProjectMemberDTO is the name of database.

Comment: but actually it is a class which is bind to the table

Comment: Replace ProjectMemberDTO  with actual underlying tablename.I just specified it as an example since i was unware of the actual table name

Comment: I mean to say in your answer ProjectMemberDTO  is the name of database table according to my understanding.is this right or not?

Comment: Yes Correct.It is a native SQL Query, meaning the same query which you will run in MYSQL Workbench

Comment: i can't write the native query ,this will make my application database dependent and then there will be no benefit of using hibernate.